# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread......Skipped 96 frames

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, oncreate, live-wallpaper

I am new to Android Development.
I recently created a slideshow live wallpaper which would change the image in every a few seconds depending on the user's selection.  I also added the login, create password, etc. as learning purpose.

I have not seen this message before until I just updated the Eclipse.  I am not if it has to do with Eclipse or my codes.
This app crashes on my Galaxy Note 2 sometimes.  There must be something wrong with the codes, but I can't figure out what causes it....

I read about Asyntask, but I don't know how to approach it.

Could you someone please help me on this?

Thank you.

prefs class:

```
public class prefs extends PreferenceActivity implements
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private CheckBoxPreference pref_checkbox;
protected static final String TAG = null;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(main_activity.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.wallpaper_settings);

    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

I have a bunch of these codes for different buttons just right below the above Oncreate.
Is it the cause of the frame skipping problems or anything wrong with them?

```
  Preference button1 = (Preference)findPreference("button1");
  button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                //code for login_password   
                return true;
            }
        });


  Preference button2 = (Preference)findPreference("button2");
  button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                //code for create_password   
                return true;
            }
        });



  Preference button3 = (Preference)findPreference("button3");
  button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                //code for reset_password   
                return true;
            }
        });
```

So on....

Edit: fixed errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I started with Android development. The app crashed everytime I called drawBitmap, or something like rotate an image. I had to move everything that manipulated images to an asynctask, and the app worked well after. Perhaps this is a solution for you as well?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think asyntask is the solution.  The problem is I don't know how to apply asyntask to my codes.  Would you or anyone else please give me some examples?  Thank  you

Comment: The Android Developer website has an example on how to process bitmaps using asynctask. Hope this helps you.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, I still don't know how to put those codes into my app :-(